# Pack shared libraries into the elf

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, elf

Is there a utility that can take **ALL** the SO's that an Elf needs turn them into static then converts the Elf to be SO's free?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some projects you might find useful:

- [Statifier](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/) (basically does what you want)
- [ERESI](http://www.eresi-project.org/wiki/TheELFsh) (might do what you want, also allows for analysis of ELF targets)

NOTE: I've not used either application myself.

Answer (score 3):

Statifier is an option. Another option is  [Ermine](http://magicErmine.com).
While Ermine is commercial it behaves better than statifier on systems with memory randomization.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Statifier as mentioned by codelogic.

It worked well for several Linux commands like ethtool.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, though in theory, no doubt, it could be done.

One aspect to be aware of - the typical program will not be using all the code from a given SO, so blindly including all the material in each SO would give you a grotesquely bloated executable.  A classic static link only includes that which is needed.

Another aspect to be aware of would be C++ template instantiation.  I assume that these would mainly appear in the executable already (not as part of an SO).

Answer (score 0):

You can link with -static at compile time.  Are you looking to do this post-compile?

Comment: could you recommend anything to do post-compile?