# linking a static library in JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am new to JNI.

I want to link a static library (say libFoo.a) into the dynamic library which I am creating. This dynamic library is being called from my Java class.

Is this possible? If so how?

```
gcc -I$JAVA_DIR/include -I$JAVA_DIR/include/linux  -o libXY.so -shared jni/xy.c libFoo.a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: I want to link a static library (say libFoo.a) into the dynamic library which I am creating.  Is this possible?

A: Sure.  Just include your .a static library in the link command where you build your shared .so.

This has nothing to do with JNI per se - *any* shared binary (*nix .so or Windows .dll) can be linked into a shared library in this fashion.

These links should help:

- [Possible to build a shared library with static link used library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344830/possible-to-build-a-shared-library-with-static-link-used-library)
- http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: What about a libtool based .la shared library like libX.la. Can I include that as well using the same method? I tried but get some errors.

Comment: What does mean "Just include your .a static library in the link command where you build your shared .so." ? Thanks.