# Building Single .so file from multiple .so files

Tags: android, android-browser, android-build, mobile-webkit

In android, I want to make a single .so file from multiple other .so files.

Example like i have libtest.so which depends on several other .so files (lie liba.so, lib.so),

So instead of linking them at runtime, i want to create a single static file from these dependent .so files.

Finally i will load .so from my android app so that it will run without need of runtime support of these libraries.

Any body have idea about that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there is NOT an easy way to finish this task. The simple way is [How to combine shared libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762427/how-to-combine-shared-libraries).
And in my developing, I built these modules both static and shared libraries. And change the dependence from `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` to `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES`. And then build them.

The steps:

1. Find all libraries you want to change to static
2. Appending a `LOCAL_MODULE` and `include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)` to the Android.mk
3. Change the dependence from *SHARED* to *STATIC*
4. Rebuild