# Could a shared library be compiled into another shared library?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

Suppose I have a shared library `A.so` on computer #1, and then I build another shared library
`B.so` on #1 which is dependent on `A.so`. My question is: could I use `B.so` in another almost the same computer #2 which does not have `A.so`?

Should there be a mechanism that I can include `A.so` in `B.so`, so I don't need `A.so` any longer?

Comment: It might be possible.  However, there is an easier way to do things: just set the rpath, and distribute A.so with B.so.

Comment: Not as far a I am aware. The other computer needs A.so. They are "Shared Objects" and not "Static libraries". If it was a A.a and B.a  then B.a could statically link A.a and what you describe would work.. Maybe someone else might know a way.. I don't :l

Comment: Find a source code of `A.so`! ;)

Comment: @DietrichEpp I am not familiar with rpath. It seems that it helps the linker to locate A.so, but here, on computer#2, there is no A.so.

Comment: @Beta Thanks. The link you gave describes the same problem as mine; however they have the source code for both A and B. I only have the source file of B.

Comment: @Drop so it is impossible to manage it without source file of A. Right ?

Comment: In that case I know of no way to do it, but I can't say that it's impossible. Everything I've read says that shared libraries can't be manipulated that way, but they don't say *why.*

Comment: See also [Pack shared libraries into the ELF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386579/pack-shared-libraries-into-the-elf) where the answers discuss some tools that might help.

Comment: @kevin: you would then distribute A.so and B.so together.  The rpath just allows you to do this without installing A.so in a privileged location, such as `/usr/lib`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Ok, then I choose to persuade the superuser to install both A and B on computer#. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the helpful information. It is time to close this post now.