# Create a single library file from several

Tags: c++

I need to build some library (let's call it library **A**) in my project. That library depends on several other libraries. When I build it I have a .dll and .lib files. Now when I try to use it, I need to include **A**'s headers, add newly created .lib and .dll to project. Moreover I need to add other .libs and .dlls. One of that libraries is Boost.

Is it possible to have as few files as possible? I don't want other team members to download Boost and build it in order to compile my code. I just want to add one single library and header from **A**.

Comment: Some of Boost is header-only stuff, and some is more involved.  Header-only you could in theory manually paste anywhere you use an #include.  I say in theory, because I don't know whether or not licensing permits it.  Might be better to use some sort of project framework that bundles what you need, and creates the appropriate makefile.

Comment: Incorporating a huge and popular library like Boost into your own is a really bad idea.  Not only might it be illegal and waste disk space, your users will also no longer profit automatically from new releases of the library.

Comment: @5gon: I always much prefer being in control over which version of some dependency my project links against. It makes issue tracking _much_ easier and you can guarantee project quality to a vastly increased degree. Allowing your users to just pick and choose 3rd party library versions is not necessarily a good thing.

Comment: And as far as shared libraries are concerned, this question might have already been discussed [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715265/could-a-shared-library-be-compiled-into-another-shared-library) and a little [less recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762427/how-to-combine-shared-libraries).

Comment: I think the Boost developers (as the developers of any serious mature library) try really hard not to break existing code with new releases easily.

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't use Boost directly. And I want my team to download/build it. If I correctly understand, using dynamic library it's not possible to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use as much as you can static libraries then - they will only include the code you need and won't create DLL dependencies from your DLL. This is not a good idea however because in this way your users won't be able to benefit from future libraries updates - as replacing dependant DLL's.

About the .lib files - your users will only need 1 of them which will expose your DLL functionality. The  libs you used to create it are not needed.

Comment: So, just to be sure, if I build static library (.lib only) I should only distribute this library and headers to it, right?

Comment: It depends of it's linkage. For example if the static library you're distributing is linked dynamically to some other libraries which DLL's are not common (eg. it is not 'ntdll.dll' or something but 'boostLib.dll') then you should also distribute them.